# Deleting large numbers of fields in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap

It there a good strategy for deleting a few thousand fields from the attribute table of a shapefile in ArcGIS using either ArcMap or ArcCatalog?

I know how to manually right-click and choose 'delete field;; I'm wondering if there is any other strategy. If I could export the shapefile with columns selected, that would also be fine, but I don't think that can be done.

Comment: do you want it to be more automated then the Delete Field geoprocessing tool? With the tool you can select all fields then just unselect a handful that you want to keep.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that tool - I'll take a look. I just tried out @Dan's method and it worked fine.

Comment: You should have a few less clicks of the mouse with the Delete Field tool. Otherwise @Dan's method is good if you want to have a copy of the orig layer.

Comment: Delete Field tool can also be scripted as part of a larger workflow, if needed. I don't think Dan's technique can be scripted.

Comment: @Kevin, Dan's method can be scripted by using ArcObjects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tested with a shapefile.

1  Right-click on the layer in ArcMap

2  Select Properties, then the Field tab

3  Select the All fields Off icon, which is beneath the General Tab

4  Toggle back on the fields that you want to keep (I am assuming that you have less fields to toggle back on than to toggle off)

5  Click OK,

6  Right-click back on the layer and select, Data, Export Data to create a new file which has the fields you want (which as minimum must contain FID, Shape and ID)

Answer (score 13):

As I commented to your question, you can use the [Delete Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Delete_Field/00170000004n000000/) tool.

Comment: I think both answers are very useful, but I choose the other one as I did it first. Wish I could mark them both as an answer....

Answer (score 1):

The Xtools extension will also do this with its "Multi Delete Fields" tool. It's one of the free tools (Xtools is a paid extension but most of its features are free if you just register with your email address).